# Form submitting even with 'return false' - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been following this tutorial from [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrycH6F-ksY)!, and it just don't want to work the way I want it to.

I got this code in my index.php:

```
<form action="scripts/keys.php" class="ajax" method="post">
    <p>Key:</p>
    <input type="text" name="key" class="key_input" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This code in my main.js:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[key]').each(function(index, value){ 
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr(''),
            value  that.val('');

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and finally this in my keys.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])) {
    echo 'lol';
}
```

For some reason when I submit the form it still sends me to keys.php, and I don't understand that, when I used return false.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Don't tell me the correct code, just what I need to change :)

Comment: As an aside, `console.log()` is not a php function.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error, missing equalsign

```
that.find('[key]').each(function(index, value){ 
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr(''),
        value  that.val('');  // HERE
//           ^^
    data[name] = value;
});
```

And change the PHP to

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])) {
    echo 'lol';
}
```

Comment: I added the = sign, but now it gives me:

Notice: Use of undefined constant console - assumed 'console' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/scripts/keys.php on line 4

Warning: log() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/scripts/keys.php on line 4

Comment: That's a PHP error, there's no console.log() in PHP, I assumed it was a joke ?

Comment: I'm new to programming, no need to make fun of me :)

Comment: But, it still sends me to keys.php even after making it echo instead.

Comment: And you included jQuery properly, put the script inside document ready etc.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: - and yes. It is inside document ready :)

Comment: It works just fine for me when testing, it does not redirect and the ajax call happens as it should -> **http://jsfiddle.net/773ht/**